# IE11 Ajax Request pending

Tags: javascript, .net

It has been  normally before. Now when it run in some win10 system and IE11. the request has been suspended.

```
if (array.length > 0) {
    var str = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var name = array[i].name;
        var age = array[i].age;
        
        if (str == "[") {
            str += '{"name":"' + name + '","age":"' + age + '"}';
        } else {
            str += ',{"name":"' + name + '","age":"' + age + '"}';
    }
    str += "]";
    if (str != "") {
        $.post('/Sys/User/SaveUser', { 'UserJson': str }, function (data) {
            
        }, 'json');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize it's not much help but IE11 support is practically over; it's likely not worth the trouble. Regardless, it might help to explain what the problem is. What error messages are you seeing? What steps have you tried yourself? There seems to be parts of the code you pasted that probably aren't relevant to the problem; I advise removing them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but the system is still running, some IE11 have this problem and I have to fix it. After post it, I tried alert someting, then it can run normally. I think it need man-made block, but I tried jQuery.Deferred(),  it didn't work

Comment: Where does it say the request has been suspended?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.